# Fragment Navigation Drawer Initializes as Open

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, navigation-drawer

I am trying to create a Navigation Drawer (it's outdated I know) with a custom layout.  I am using a fragment within the NavDrawer to accomplish this.
The problem I am having is that when I run my app, my navigation drawer is automatically opening and I have no way to close it / no idea how.  I suspect it has to do with the `.commit()` method at the end of my fragment transaction.

So my question is how do I get the nav drawer, housing a fragment, to operate like a normal nav drawer that only contains a ListView where it can be dragged in and out?  Or if a fragment causes too many difficulties in a nav drawer is there another way for a super custom layout inside of a nav drawer?  Thanks in advance!

Here is what it looks like. Code is below picture...

[image: NavigationDrawer opens and does not close]

in MapsActivity.java:

```
//Instantiates Fragment inside of our Nav Drawer        
    NavigationDrawerFragment navDrawerFragment = new                    NavigationDrawerFragment();
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.navDrawer_container,
navDrawerFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

activity_maps.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorMapToolbar"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp">
        <!-- contentInsert is the initial padding that is added by the system at the start -->


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/topLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/back_action"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="6dp"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_goleft" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/locker"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="6dp"
                android:src="@drawable/lock_open" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/dropshadow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@drawable/dropshadow_dark" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionImageButton"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_location" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/markerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/colorMapToolbar"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/markerCancel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/cancel"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_large_material" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/markerMark"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/mark"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_large_material"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
<!-- FRAGMENT CONTAINER -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/navDrawer_container"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

fragment_navigation_drawer.xml: (accompanied by a .java for Fragment but it is not relevant here)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="200dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="2"
android:background="@android:color/white">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/topRowLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userTitleBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="@string/userTitle"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/alertTitleBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="@string/alertTitle"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/lastFlamText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/lastFlameTitle"
        android:layout_below="@+id/userTitleBtn" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/scoreTextNavDrawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:textSize="100sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lastFlamText" />

</RelativeLayout>


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/navList"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="left|start"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `android:layout_gravity="left|start"` attribute needs to go on the `navDrawer_container` `FrameLayout` in the `activity_maps` layout. This attribute lets the `DrawerLayout` know that this `View` is the drawer. The fact that it's missing would explain why your drawer is "open" on startup, and immovable.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/navDrawer_container"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left|start" />
```

You don't necessarily need that attribute now on the `ListView` in the `fragment_navigation_drawer` layout.

Answer (score 0):

Add this Code in your activity or Fragment

```
@Override
      public void onStart() {
             super.onStart();
             if (drawer_layout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.LEFT)) {
                 drawer_layout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
             }
         }
```